# Can't update or add menu in admin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, hide, hidden, wpml

i Have a problem with (Menu) in admin wordpress, i can't add or update any menu in admin, I use WPML for translation.
and i have not acces to menu by ID in the link exemple: wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=161

help please!

[Menu hidden WMPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7p0P.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a menu for each language and then add the items.